# Delphi collaborate function

Tags: delphi, collaboration

Is there a way to collaborate in Delphi 11 like the JetBrain's "code with me feature"? I want my friend to code with me, working on the same Delphi project.

I have searched all over but am finding nothing on the internet.

Comment: Use a GitHub repo together with your friend

Comment: Easy answer: No

Answer (score 0):

No. Delphi 11 does not have any such feature.